# Rails Devise and devise_token_auth. Not working alongside

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, token

I have a Rails 4.1 Application running with Devise for authentication.

For access via mobile apps i would like to implement token auth with the recommended devise_token_auth gem. I do not use Omniauth

The functionality of the existing app should not be altered.

What i did:

Installed devise_token_auth via gemfile.

Used the generator: rails g devise_token_auth:install User auth

Changed the migration to add the required fields.
Migration failed due missing of Omniauth. So i also installed it.

Changed routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:sessions, :registrations, :omniauth_callbacks]
  as :user do
    get 'register' => 'users/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
    post 'register' => 'users/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
    get 'sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'sign_in' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete '/' => 'users/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end
```

added:

```
namespace :api do
scope :v1 do
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', skip: [:omniauth_callbacks]
end
```

end

In User Model i have:

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
     :confirmable, :timeoutable, :lockable
include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
```

Now when i try to sign_up a new user it gives me the validation error:

Uid can't be blank

Does someone had the same problem and resolved it?

What i find strange is that it needs to have Omniauth installed.

Update:

I overwrite the Devise registration controller create action:

```
build_resource(sign_up_params)
 resource.uid = resource.email
 resource.provider = ''
```

Now when i sign_in i get:

{"errors":["Authorized users only."]}

in Browser.

Comment: which version of the gem are you using? I'm trying to do the same but I get an error.

Comment: currently: devise_token_auth 0.1.32.beta2

Comment: You said you "Changed the migration to add the required fields." What were these? Was there a guide you followed? I'm trying to add devise_token_auth to my existing, customized Devise implementation.

Answer (score 5):

Adding the following to app/models/user.rb:

```
before_validation do
  self.uid = email if uid.blank?  
end
```

did it for me. Also make sure the provider is set to "email" for "provider".

Comment: This worked for me, any idea why ? What should the uid be typically ? @Thirdium

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm currently struggling with the same thing. Trying to add `devise_token_auth` to Devise, and it is not working so far for me.

As far as this goes, are you talking about "sign_up" for Devise, or `devise_token_auth`? If it is for Devise, I supposed setting `uid=email` before creating the record would solve this.

Comment: I need to have both. Sign up via Devise and via devise_token_auth

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised by devise_token_auth, not by devise. So essentially, devise_token_auth is trying to authenticate your normal devise routes the same way it would normally authenticate an api request. Your normal devise routes are authenticating via session, not via token, so you'll get this error:

```
{"errors":["Authorized users only."]}
```

There are a couple of things that could be happening here. First, make sure that you're only looking for token validation on the actions of your API controllers. So make sure that this line is included in your BaseAPIController, and not in your ApplicationController.

```
include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::SetUserByToken
```

The other possibility is that you have some namespacing issues in your routes.rb. Make sure that you have something like this. You need to have devise_for first, and the token_auth properly namespaced or it will cause validations issues on your other routes.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :admins

  namespace :api do
    scope :v1 do
      mount_devise_token_auth_for 'user', at: 'auth'
    end
  end
end
```

Good luck!